# **System.MissingMethodException:** 'Method not found: void

Tags: xamarin.forms

When I try to run my Xamarin Forms project and click on the login button on the main page, I get the below exception:

> **System.MissingMethodException:** 'Method not found: void AndroidHUD.AndHUD.Show(Android.Content.Context,string,int,AndroidHUD.MaskType,System.Nullable`1<System.TimeSpan>,System.Action,bool,System.Action)'

I tried cleaning and rebuilding my solution, deleting my obj and bin folders, and updating the NuGet packages, but that didn't help.

Below is the login button clicked code where I'm getting the exception:

```
public async void LoginButtonClicked(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UserDialogs.Instance.ShowLoading("Signing in...");
    var name = usernameEntry.Text;
    var password = passwordEntry.Text;
    var domain = domainnameEntry.Text;
    if (Utility.IsInternet())
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(domain))
        {
            Utility.isTokenRefresh = false;
            await Utility.GetAccessToken();
            if (Utility.isTokenRefresh)
            {
                GetSiteId(name, password, domain);
            }
            else
            {
                UserDialogs.Instance.HideLoading();
                ShowAlert("Failed to fetch the access token, please try again later.");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            UserDialogs.Instance.HideLoading();
            if (!Utility.IsWindowsDevice())
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Alert", "Please enter all details.", "Ok");
            }
            else
            {
                ShowAlert("Please enter all details.");
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        UserDialogs.Instance.HideLoading();
        if (!Utility.IsWindowsDevice())
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Alert", "No internet connection.", "Ok");
        }
        else
        {
            ShowAlert("No internet connection.");
        }
    }
}
```

How can I fix this issue? Please suggest a solution.

**Update:**
I tried installing the AndHUD version 1.4.3 and installed the Acr.UserDialogs version 7.2.0.561 nuget package to the Android project. But, when trying to install the Acr.UserDialogs version 7.2.0.561 nuget package to the shared project, I get the below error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error       Could not install package 'Acr.UserDialogs 7.2.0.561'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile111', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

My project is a portable type project.

Comment: which line causes the exception?

Comment: @Jason `UserDialogs.Instance.ShowLoading("Signing in...");` This line cause the issue. If I comment that line the app is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there is [a similar issue on the github](https://github.com/redth-org/AndHUD/issues/41) that has the same error message as yours. You can refer to it.

And then I can't reproduce your problem in my project. Here are my steps to test your code:

1. Install the **Acr.UserDialogs version 7.2.0.56**1 nuget package both in the share project and the android part project.
2. Init the UserDialogs in the MainActivity : Call the `UserDialogs.Init(this);` in the **MainActivity's OnCreate() method**.
3. Call the `UserDialogs.Instance.ShowLoading("Signing in...");` in the MainPage's button clicked event.

Everthing worked well and the dialog will show. According to the error message, you can try to install the `AndHUD version 1.4.3` in your android party project to resolve it.

**Update:**

Here is my share project's csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <ProduceReferenceAssembly>true</ProduceReferenceAssembly>
    <ProduceReferenceAssemblyInOutDir>true</ProduceReferenceAssemblyInOutDir>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <DebugType>portable</DebugType>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Acr.UserDialogs" Version="7.2.0.561" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="5.0.0.2196" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Essentials" Version="1.7.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: I have updated the question with the findings for the solution you suggested.

Comment: If so, what version did you installed when you test it first time? @MatthewPans

Comment: You can refer to my csproj file in the update part. In addition, you can try to install the Acr.UserDialogs version 6.5.1 in your share project and android paroject instead of Acr.UserDialogs version 7.2.0.561 to test at first. @MatthewPans